# Переход с VB.NET на C#

Tags: vb.net, c#

Скажите я решил перейти на C#, хочу нормально программировать, скажите как быстро перейти? Чтобы не путаться в переменных и.т.д, может книга есть "Быстрый старт C#" просто я многие сайты облазил, там книги за Visual C# 2005, а щяс уже 2010.

Comment: А я пишу на Delphi и читаю книги по Паскалю за 1997 год какой кошмар.
Если вам программирование не дано, то никакая книга не поможет, а если дано, то и с чужого исходника разберетесь.

Comment: С# более интенсивно развивается по сравнению с Delphi, различия, например, между .Net 2.0 и 3.5 крайне велики

Comment: Delphi тоже на месте не стоит, мой ответ был посвящен другому.
Что если человек хочет учить он учит, а если хочет попонтоватся то будет искать книгу за следующий гол.

Comment: Если человек хочет идти в ногу со временем?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Программирование на C# с нуля](http://simple-cs.ru/) - на мой взгляд лучший материал для старта.

Потом книги:

- Джефри Рихтер "C# via .Net"("CLR via C#" в оригинале)
- Троелсен Э. "Язык программирования C# 2010 и платформа .NET 4 - 2010"
- Джозеф Албахари "C# 4.0 in a Nutshell" 4th Edition - мой фаворит

P.S. уже есть уйма ответов на подобные вопросы на данном ресурсе.

Comment: Устраивает ответ - примите его.